# How many fields are required for Create Passenger Name Record REST API call?

Tags: rest, sabre

According to your REST API documentation for Create Passenger Name Record how many fields are required to send RQ as in description([enter link description here](http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/STPS/create_passenger_name_record/v100/CreatePassengerNameRecord_v1.0.0_Request_Description.html)) there are approx. 266 fields are required is that true? How can i get the detail information of required fields?

Answer (score 4):

Many elements are required if an optional element is used, for example:

If you use: **CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.Profile** that it is not required **Required: false**

The you must use **CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.Profile.UniqueID**, **Required: true**

Since these services follow the old Sabre logic, the mandatory elements are what it used to be called PRINT:

> P - Phone number
>   R - Received from
>   I - Itinerary
>   N - Name of traveler
>   T - Ticketing time limit

So, this would be the bare minimum:

```
CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.TravelItineraryAddInfo.CustomerInfo
CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.TravelItineraryAddInfo.CustomerInfo.ContactNumbers
CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.TravelItineraryAddInfo.CustomerInfo.ContactNumbers.ContactNumber

CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.PostProcessing.EndTransaction
CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.PostProcessing.EndTransaction.Source
CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.PostProcessing.EndTransaction.Source.ReceivedFrom

CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.AirBook
(There's a bunch of elements for this, so I will not copy them)

CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.TravelItineraryAddInfo.CustomerInfo
CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.TravelItineraryAddInfo.CustomerInfo.PersonName
CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.TravelItineraryAddInfo.CustomerInfo.PersonName.GivenName 
CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.TravelItineraryAddInfo.CustomerInfo.PersonName.Surname

CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.TravelItineraryAddInfo
CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.TravelItineraryAddInfo.AgencyInfo.Ticketing
CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.TravelItineraryAddInfo.AgencyInfo.Ticketing.TicketType
```