# REST API 'Create Passenger Name Record' Warning and errors

Tags: rest, api, sabre

The below attached warnings and error occurred while testing Booking seat.
There is no any proper documentation of Create Passenger Name Record REST API Call, the [description](http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/STPS/create_passenger_name_record/v100/CreatePassengerNameRecord_v1.0.0_Request_Description.html) and [schema](http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/STPS/create_passenger_name_record/v100/CreatePassengerNameRecord_v1.0.0_Request.jsonschema) are meaning less. In description there are 266 parameters are required true to send a request.

Do you have any proper documentation where i can get all the required parameters detailed information? Like What is SegmentNumber how can i get?

**Working flow( For Single trip) :**

1. Get the origin, destination, date, number of seats required.
2. Send all required parms to Bargain Finder Max, get the response
3. Send Require params to book a seat. Create Passenger Name Record

**Request**

```
{
    "CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
        "targetCity": "3QND",
        "Profile": {
            "UniqueID": {
                "ID": "ABCD1EF"
            }
        },
              "AirBook": {
            "OriginDestinationInformation": {
                "FlightSegment": [{
                    "ArrivalDateTime": "2017-04-30",
                    "DepartureDateTime": "2017-04-30T13:55",
                    "FlightNumber": "309",
                    "NumberInParty": "1",
                    "ResBookDesigCode": "V",
                    "Status": "NN",
                    "DestinationLocation": {
                        "LocationCode": "KHI"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "PK",
                        "FlightNumber": "309"
                    },
                    "MarriageGrp": "O",
                    "OriginLocation": {
                        "LocationCode": "ISB"
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        "AirPrice": {
            "PriceRequestInformation": {
                "OptionalQualifiers": {
                    "MiscQualifiers": {
                        "TourCode": {
                            "Text": "TEST1212"
                        }
                    },
                    "PricingQualifiers": {
                        "PassengerType": [{
                            "Code": "CNN",
                            "Quantity": "1"
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "MiscSegment": {
            "DepartureDateTime": "2017-04-30",
            "NumberInParty": 1,
            "Status": "NN",
            "Type": "OTH",
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "ISB"
            },
            "Text": "TEST",
            "VendorPrefs": {
                "Airline": {
                    "Code": "PK"
                }
            }
        },
        "SpecialReqDetails": {
            "AddRemark": {
                "RemarkInfo": {
                    "FOP_Remark": {
                        "Type": "CHECK",
                        "CC_Info": {
                            "Suppress": true,
                            "PaymentCard": {
                                "AirlineCode": "PK",
                                "CardSecurityCode": "1234",
                                "Code": "VI",
                                "ExpireDate": "2012-12",
                                "ExtendedPayment": "12",
                                "ManualApprovalCode": "123456",
                                "Number": "4123412341234123",
                                "SuppressApprovalCode": true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "FutureQueuePlaceRemark": {
                        "Date": "12-21",
                        "PrefatoryInstructionCode": "11",
                        "PseudoCityCode": "IPCC1",
                        "QueueIdentifier": "499",
                        "Time": "06:00"
                    },
                    "Remark": [{
                        "Type": "Historical",
                        "Text": "TEST HISTORICAL REMARK"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Invoice",
                        "Text": "TEST INVOICE REMARK"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Itinerary",
                        "Text": "TEST ITINERARY REMARK"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Hidden",
                        "Text": "TEST HIDDEN REMARK"
                    }]
                }
            },
            "AirSeat": {
                "Seats": {
                    "Seat": [{
                        "NameNumber": "1.1",
                        "Preference": "AN",
                        "SegmentNumber": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "NameNumber": "2.1",
                        "Preference": "AN",
                        "SegmentNumber": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "NameNumber": "3.1",
                        "Preference": "AN",
                        "SegmentNumber": "1"
                    }]
                }
            },
            "SpecialService": {
                "SpecialServiceInfo": {
                    "Service": [{
                        "SSR_Code": "OSI",
                        "PersonName": {
                            "NameNumber": "testing"
                         #},
                        "Text": "TEST1",
                        "VendorPrefs": {
                            "Airline": {
                                "Code": "PK"
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
        "PostProcessing": {
            "RedisplayReservation": true,
            "ARUNK": "",
            "QueuePlace": {
                "QueueInfo": {
                    "QueueIdentifier": [{
                        "Number": "100",
                        "PrefatoryInstructionCode": "11"
                    }]
                }
            },
            "EndTransaction": {
                "Source": {
                    "ReceivedFrom": "SWS TEST"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "CreatePassengerNameRecordRS": {
        "ApplicationResults": {
            "status": "NotProcessed",
            "Error": [
                {
                    "type": "Application",
                    "timeStamp": "2017-03-08T04:10:41.317-06:00",
                    "SystemSpecificResults": [
                        {
                            "Message": [
                                {
                                    "code": "ERR.SP.BUSINESS_ERROR",
                                    "content": "PNR has not been created successfully, see remaining messages for details"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Warning": [
                {
                    "type": "BusinessLogic",
                    "timeStamp": "2017-03-08T04:10:40.628-06:00",
                    "SystemSpecificResults": [
                        {
                            "Message": [
                                {
                                    "code": "WARN.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR",
                                    "content": "NO PROFILE FOUND FOR NAME"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Validation",
                    "timeStamp": "2017-03-08T04:10:40.655-06:00",
                    "SystemSpecificResults": [
                        {
                            "Message": [
                                {
                                    "code": "WARN.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED",
                                    "content": "Request contains incorrect values: Wrong dateTime format"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "BusinessLogic",
                    "timeStamp": "2017-03-08T04:10:40.919-06:00",
                    "SystemSpecificResults": [
                        {
                            "Message": [
                                {
                                    "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE",
                                    "content": "FORMAT, CHECK SEGMENT NUMBER-0003"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "BusinessLogic",
                    "timeStamp": "2017-03-08T04:10:41.024-06:00",
                    "SystemSpecificResults": [
                        {
                            "Message": [
                                {
                                    "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE",
                                    "content": ".DTE.NOT ENT BGNG WITH"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "BusinessLogic",
                    "timeStamp": "2017-03-08T04:10:41.062-06:00",
                    "SystemSpecificResults": [
                        {
                            "Message": [
                                {
                                    "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE",
                                    "content": "\u0087ND NAMES\u0087"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "BusinessLogic",
                    "timeStamp": "2017-03-08T04:10:41.096-06:00",
                    "SystemSpecificResults": [
                        {
                            "Message": [
                                {
                                    "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE",
                                    "content": "\u0087ND NAMES\u0087"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "BusinessLogic",
                    "timeStamp": "2017-03-08T04:10:41.129-06:00",
                    "SystemSpecificResults": [
                        {
                            "Message": [
                                {
                                    "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE",
                                    "content": "\u0087ND NAMES\u0087"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "BusinessLogic",
                    "timeStamp": "2017-03-08T04:10:41.166-06:00",
                    "SystemSpecificResults": [
                        {
                            "Message": [
                                {
                                    "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE",
                                    "content": "NO ARNK INSERTED"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "BusinessLogic",
                    "timeStamp": "2017-03-08T04:10:41.229-06:00",
                    "SystemSpecificResults": [
                        {
                            "Message": [
                                {
                                    "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE",
                                    "content": "NEED PHONE FIELD - USE 9"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "TravelItineraryRead": {
            "TravelItinerary": {
                "CustomerInfo": {
                },
                "ItineraryInfo": {
                    "ReservationItems": {
                        "Item": [
                            {
                                "RPH": "1",
                                "MiscSegment": {
                                    "DayOfWeekInd": "7",
                                    "DepartureDateTime": "04-30",
                                    "NumberInParty": "01",
                                    "SegmentNumber": "0001",
                                    "Status": "NN",
                                    "Type": "OTH",
                                    "IsPast": false,
                                    "OriginLocation": {
                                        "LocationCode": "ISB"
                                    },
                                    "Text": [
                                        "TEST"
                                    ],
                                    "Vendor": {
                                        "Code": "PK"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "ItineraryRef": {
                    "AirExtras": false,
                    "InhibitCode": "U",
                    "PartitionID": "AA",
                    "PrimeHostID": "1B",
                    "Header": [
                        "CURRENTLY DISPLAYING A PNR OWNED BY THE SABRE PRIME HOST",
                        "RULES AND FUNCTIONALITY FOR THAT PRIME HOST WILL APPLY"
                    ],
                    "Source": {
                        "PseudoCityCode": "3QND",
                        "ReceivedFrom": "SWS TEST"
                    }
                },
                "SpecialServiceInfo": [
                    {
                        "RPH": "001",
                        "Type": "GFX",
                        "Service": {
                            "SSR_Code": "OSI",
                            "Airline": {
                                "Code": "PK"
                            },
                            "Text": [
                                "TEST1-TESTING"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https:\/\/api.sabre.com\/v1.0.0\/passenger\/records?mode=create"
        },
        {
            "rel": "linkTemplate",
            "href": "https:\/\/api.sabre.com\/\/passenger\/records?mode="
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what errors or warnings you are getting?

Comment: "code": "ERR.SP.BUSINESS_ERROR",
                                    "content": "PNR has not been created successfully, see remaining messages for details" see above response array for detail warnings and errors.

Answer (score 2):

Please avoid posting the same questions. Here's an answer I just posted regarding the required elements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42671412/3701641

About the segment number, they represent the itinerary segments, you are adding one flight segment, so the segment number associated with that would be 1.